# How to handle dynamic properties within a class using Angular 2 with AngularFire2

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am wondering what is the best practice to handle dynamic properties within a class using Angular 2 with AngularFire2.

In my Firebase DB I have the following scheme:

```
$company
- users
-- $user
--- public
--- chats
--- events
---- $event
----- id
----- timestamp
- events
-- $event
--- id
--- timestamp
--- joiners
---- $joiner
----- uid
```

I implemented a User service:

```
// UserService
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private dbService: DatabaseService) {}

  getUser(uid: string): Observable<User> {
    console.log('Retrieveing user for uid ', uid);

    let now: number = Date.now();

    return Observable.combineLatest(
      this.dbService.getNodeAsObjectObservable(true, `users/${uid}/public`),
      this.dbService.getNodeAsListObservable(true, `users/${uid}/events`, {
        query: {
          orderByChild: 'timestamp',
          startAt: now
        }
      })
    ).map(([info, joinedEvents]) => (new User({uid, info, joinedEvents})));
  }
}
```

A Database service:

```
@Injectable()
    export class DatabaseService {
      public root: any;
      public queue: any;
      public company: any;

      constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
        console.log('DatabaseService constructor');
      }

      setCompany(company: string): void {
        this.company = company;
      }

      // Utilities
      getNodeAsListObservable(companyRelated: boolean, node: string, query?: any): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
        console.log('DatabaseService - getNodeAsListObservable: with args ',
          companyRelated, node, query
        );
        let ref: string;

        companyRelated ? ref = this.company : ref = this.root;

        if (query) {
          return this.af.database.list(`${ref}/${node}`, query);
        } else {
          return this.af.database.list(`${ref}/${node}`);
        }

      }
      getNodeAsObjectObservable(companyRelated: boolean, node: string): FirebaseObjectObservable<any> {
        let ref: any;

        companyRelated ? ref = this.company : ref = this.root;

        return this.af.database.object(`${ref}/${node}`);

      }
}
```

In my home.ts:

```
user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private userService: UserService) {
    console.log('HomePage constructor');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Retrieve current user
    this.user = this.userService.getUser('abizhdiuh738937bj');
  }
```

And finally my User class is defined as follows:

```
export interface IUser {
  uid: string;
  info: any;
  //joinedEvents?:
}

export class User implements IUser {
  uid: string;
  info: any;
  joinedEvents?: FirebaseListObservable<Event>;
  constructor(obj?: any) {
    if (obj.uid) this.uid = obj.uid;
    if (obj.info) this.info = obj.info;
    if (obj.joinedEvents) {
      for (let i = 0; i < obj.joinedEvents.length; i++) {
        // Q1: how to retrieve details of each event
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For each joinedEvents I want to retrieve the details of it before displaying it in view.

So my question is what is the best way to pull this off?

I had several ideas:

1. in User constructor call a getEvent(event_id) function that returns a FirebaseObservableList
2. in getUser() (in UserService) once

   this.dbService.getNodeAsListObservable(true, `users/${uid}/events`, {
           query: {
             orderByChild: 'timestamp',
             startAt: now
           }
         })

   is completed call a getEvent(event_id) function. How to even do that?
3. what should this function return an Observable? Ideally as I did for User I would like to use an Event class (but may be I am wrong to willing this...)

I am pretty lost on how to handle such encapsulated complexity. Also I will have to handle something pretty similar with chats each user belongs to... Hope you can help. Thanks

Comment: Why are you injecting AngularFire into the UserService, it is not used there, resp., only indirectly via your dbService?

Comment: You are right, that's an old piece of code that I forgot to remove. But that wasn't my initial point